# Maytag Dishwasher not powering on

Tags: wiring, dishwasher

So I got a new Maytag dishwasher(MDB4949SKZ) and when installed it did not power on. No LED or indication of power. Pulled out out a multimeter and 120V on hot and 60V on Neutral. We suspected faulty board. (also this is hardlined)

We got a replacement and same thing. 120V Hot 60V neutral. Is it that i got another "lemon" or is there something else that could be wrong here.

Both Hot and neutral coming off the breaker is 120V, and no signs of damage to wires or breaker.

Any help or ideas appreciated. TIA

Comment: Hot to neutral and hot to ground should read 120v.  Neutral to ground should read 0v.  If you get different readings, then there is a problem somewhere.  Test the receptacle/outlet by itself first, without the dishwasher plugged in.

Comment: I bet a light bulb also doesn't work on this circuit.

Comment: the dishwasher cannot cause the 60V reading

Comment: Cannot believe you got a replaacement DW when clearly the circuit is not delivering the correct power!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you should be getting **ANY THING** more than a volt or two between neutral and ground, preferably zero.  I don't see any way a defective DW could cause this.  You have a wiring problem.  Most likely a lost neutral someplace.  Could be caused by anything, including rodent damage.